# PHP convert string key array to multi key array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this array:

```
$array['a.b.c'] = 'x';
$array['a.b.d'] = 'y';
$array['e.f'] = 'z';
```

what want convert to this array:

```
$array['a']['b']['c'] = 'x';
$array['a']['b']['d'] = 'y';
$array['e']['f'] = 'z';
```

is in PHP any fast way how to do it please?

Thanks
O.

Comment: Foreach loop exlode key on period

Comment: Could convert it to string, rebuild, and use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php): `$arr_str = "new['".implode("']['", explode(".", key($arr)))."']=".current($arr); parse_str($arr_str); print_r($new);` See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/417076)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using a `foreach` that iterates through each key of the array, explodes it, and uses the exploded values as keys for a new array:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $new_keys = explode('.',$key);
    $last_key = array_pop($new_keys); //remove last key from $new_keys 
    $a =& $result; //make $a and $result be the same variable

    foreach($new_keys as $new_key) {
        if(!isset($a[$new_key])) {
            $a[$new_key] = array();
        }

        $a =& $a[$new_key]; //reset $a to $a[$new_key]
    }

    $a[$last_key] = $value; //put $value in the last key
}

print_r($result);
```